# Who is performing these actions

Tags: grammar

In the extract below I am a bit unsure as to who is performing the parts in bold. Story is told from 相葉's point of view.

名残惜しむように doesn't look like something I imagine someone would use to describe their own actions (although I could be wrong). This leads me to think that the actor for 名残惜しむように手の指を絡めあって is 八城, however I am thinking that it could possibly be referring to them both.

> 相葉「バレないように、気をつけて帰るんだぞ」
>
> 八城「うん、ありがと、相葉」
>
> 相葉「また後でな」
>
> 八城「うん、後で、ね」
>
> **名残惜しむように手の指を絡めあってから、きゅっと握り**。
>
> **そして離すと**、八城は潤んだ目で俺を見て。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 名残惜{なごりお}しむように手{て}の指{ゆび}を絡{から}めあってから、きゅっと握{にぎ}り。
>
> そして離{はな}すと、八城{やしろ}は潤{うる}んだ目{め}で俺{おれ}を見{み}て。

The key word here is 「あう/合う」 in 「絡め**あって**」.　It is written in kana because it is a subsidiary verb in this phrase.

It **always** takes at least two persons to:

> 「Verb in Continuative Form + あう」
>
> "doing something **to/for/with/toward each other**."

If you are performing an action ***solo***, you cannot use 「あう/合う」 in the first place.  So, we say 「愛しあう」、「殺しあう」、「助けあう」、「見つめあう」, etc.

Thus, it is most natural to conclude that the unmentioned subjects of all of the verb phrases should be the ***two characters***.

「名残惜しむ」 = "to be reluctant to leave (each other)"

「手の指を絡めあって」 = "laced our fingers (and)"

「握り」 = "held our hands"

「そして離すと」 = "and let go of our hands"